# Select dynamic column based on value of another column?

Tags: sql, case, intersystems-cache

Given the following table, I would like to dynamically select the `Name1` or `Name2` field based on the value of the `WhichName` column.

```
id  Name1   Name2   WhichName   SomeValue
1   Bob     James   1           Blue
2           Steve   2           Horse
3   Fred            1           Radish
```

The results should look like this:

```
id  Name    SomeValue
1   Bob     Blue
2   Steve   Horse
3   Fred    Radish
```

DBMS is Caché

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when WhichName = 1 then Name1 else Name2 end) as Name,
       SomeValue
from <table>;
```

Note:  if your prefer `Name1`, unless it is `NULL`, then you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
select id, coalesce(Name1, Name2) as Name, SomeValue
from <table>;
```

Comment: That works but I can't have the open-ended `else`.  How can I do multiple cases?

Comment: Also, thanks but the coalesce option won't work for my needs.

Comment: I figured out the multiple WHEN thing, but you might update your answer to reflect it anyway.  It's very useful.